# How can I load an asset from a file after I exported the build?

Tags: assets, godot

I am seeking possibility to switch character textures for game, even after I have compiled and built the binary.

For example I have a troll with a Sprite from "/assets/texture1.png"

Now after the game has been released, I can change this sprite.

Currently I have found this method

```
func _ready():
    var texture = load("res://textures/troll1.png")
    sprite.texture = texture
```

But after the export, when I change the `troll1.png`, the texture in the game remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my question.

First mistake i did, was that i did not copy my assets folder to my game export folder, so the game never found the assets, pretty dumb...

Also, i will put some methods how to load images without using Godot automatic importer.

The simplest is this method

```
var texture = ImageTexture.new()
    texture.load("textures/troll1.png");
    $Sprite.texture = texture
```

And 2 methods that was posted on reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/eojih/how_to_load_images_without_importer/

```
var file = File.new()
var image = Image.new()

file.open("/path/to/image.png", File.READ)
image.load_png_from_buffer(file.get_buffer(file.get_len()))

file.close()
image.lock()
```

```
var path = "/path/to/image.png"

var file = File.new()
var image = Image.new()

file.open(path, File.READ)
var buffer = file.get_buffer(file.get_len())

match path.get_extension():
    "png":
        image.load_png_from_buffer(buffer)
    "jpg":
        image.load_jpg_from_buffer(buffer)

file.close()
image.lock()

var texture = ImageTexture.new()
    texture.create_from_image(image);
    $Sprite.texture = texture
```